# Print Form Data Into Array As 'value"

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

Learning my first php search form, be gentle!

I'm looking to fill the 'value' with the number input on the search form. Everything I have tried either breaks the page or has no effect.

I'm trying to input my $input_price into the value part of my argument.

Here is my search form

```
<form method="post" action="http://mysite/searchresults">
<fieldset>

<!-- TEXT INPUT SELECTION -->
<input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<!-- END TEXT INPUT SELECTION -->
<input type="text" name="input_price"/>
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is the receiving page

```
<?php 


    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => '($input_price)',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        'order' => 'DSC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :                 $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>          
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your data is being sent to the receiving script via the [POST HTTP method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), so you can access those variables with [PHP's `$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) using the element's `name` attribute as the key:

```
$input_price = $_POST['input_price'];
```

Next, the brackets around `$input_price` should not be used here. Finally, single quotes do not parse variables inside them, as in this example:

```
'value' => '($input_price)',
```

But double quotes will, or simply not using quotes at all:

```
'value' => "$input_price",
'value' => $input_price,
```

Comment: You make it sound so easy. Thank you for the answer as well as an explanation so i don't make the same mistake! This makes my day